# If $\sqrt{9^x - 6^x} = \sqrt{6^x - 4^x}$, then the number of values of $x$ are:

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, roots, radicals

> If $\sqrt{9^x - 6^x} = \sqrt{6^x - 4^x}$, then the number of values of $x$ are:

I have solved the above like this:

$\sqrt{9^x - 6^x} = \sqrt{6^x - 4^x}$

Squaring:

$9^x - 6^x = 6^x - 4^x$

$9^x + 4^x = 2\times(6^x)$

$3^{2x} + 2^{2x} = 2\times (3\times2)^{x}$

$(3^{x} - 2^{x})^{2} = 0$

Giving us, $3^x = 2^x$, so $x=0$ is the only value which satisfies.

But in the answers, they have stated that total solutions are $3$. Where have I made a mistake? And at what step did a specific action lead to loss of roots?

Please help me to go about the same. Thanks!

Comment: What you've done looks right to me.

Comment: I don;t see any other real solutions.  Do you have a link to this problem?

Comment: I did it in another way and I got the same answer.

Comment: I'm afraid, I do not have a link to the problem. It's from an old book.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Please share your answer too sir. It would give me more insight.

Comment: Are you looking for real solutions for $x$ or complex ones as well? As far as I see it, there are an infinite number of complex solutions given by $x=\frac{4\,\mathrm{j}\,\pi\,n}{\mathrm{ln}(2)-\mathrm{ln}(3)}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Here is a slightly different way of getting the same answer:\begin{align}9^x-6^x=6^x-4^x&\iff\left(\frac32\right)^{2x}-2\left(\frac32\right)^x+1=0\\&\iff\left(\left(\frac32\right)^x-1\right)^2=0\\&\iff\left(\frac32\right)^x=1\\&\iff x=0.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Factorize the equation

$$\sqrt{9^x - 6^x} - \sqrt{6^x - 4^x}
=\sqrt{3^x(3^x - 2^x)}- \sqrt{2^x(3^x - 2^x)}\\
= \sqrt{3^x - 2^x}\left(\sqrt{3^x}-\sqrt{2^x} \right)=0
$$